# Depth and range for FDR/CVR black box detection

Tags: commercial-aviation, avionics, flight-data-recorder, cockpit-voice-recorder

What is the maximum depth range of a FDR underwater, at which it is able to be detected by receivers?

I want to know the maximum range of ULB pinger locator if it's submerged.

Answer (score -1):

The maximum range if it's transmitting on 37.5kHz is usually between 1 and 2 kilometers in poor conditions and around 4 to 5 kilometers in normal conditions and up to 6 or 7 in good conditions. The range depends on the frequency it's transmitting but the ULB's work on 37.5kHz.